# Mining or buy Ether?

Tags: mining, ether

I need ether to make transactions. Actually I'm working on the testnet Ropsten network then it's easy to get ether with a miner. But if I mine blocks on the main network this will take more than one year to get just one ether. And I see we can buy ether.

I want to know if it's worth it to buy ether ? What is the best way to get some ether to use ethereum in production ?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Mining on a standard computer ceased to be feasible long ago. Another option is hiring a mining rig, I do not have experience in doing that, but I suspect it will be somewhere below or on the border of profitability, with the added cost of needing constant attention. The only way for a normal mortal to get Ether right now is to buy it, most likely at an exchange.

**EDIT:** I did not mention pool mining, which is just dividing the mining among more participants, so that you get paid almost immediately and do not have to wait until you mine a block. Most mining nowadays is done via a pool. Note that you usually pay a small fee to the pool owner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I seen we can mine in pool. Do you know something about that ?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score -2):

It better to buy a Multi coin GPU miner from pandaminer supports ETH, Zcash, Monero. check this https://www.mininghardwares.com/pandaminer-b3-plus-power-supply

Comment: Welcome Priyesh. This sort of answer may run afoul of the forum guidelines. Are you associated with Pandaminer?